# Doesn't delete the whole things in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with angular and typescript.
I have a problem in my deleting files.
I have three interfaces: Project, SubProject and Position.
Project has an subProjectIds that if I add subproject in the selectedProject this goes to the subProjectIds at interface of Project.
So it is with the Position at SubProject.

When I delete a project subproject is not deleted so the position is not deleted. I want when I delete one project automatically all subprojects and position that are connected in that selected project to be deleted.
Here is the code when I delete Project or SubProject.

```
deleteProject(project) {
    const text = 'Are you sure to delete this project ?';
    this.dialog
        .open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { data: text, disableClose: true })
        .afterClosed()
        .subscribe((result: boolean) => result &&
            this.store.dispatch(new DeleteProjectInternalAction(project.id)));
}

deleteSubProject(subproject) {
    const text = 'Are you sure to delete this SubProject ?';
    this.dialog
        .open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, {
            data: text,
            disableClose: true
        })
        .afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
            if (result) {
                this.store.dispatch(new DeleteSubProjectInternalAction(subproject.id));
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the when I add a SubProject.

```
save() {
    if (this.newSubProjectName.length > 0) {
        this.working = true;
        const newSubProject: SubProject = emptySubProject();
        newSubProject.name = this.newSubProjectName;
        newSubProject.id = Math.random().toString();
        newSubProject.color = this.newSubProjectColor;
        newSubProject.positionIds = this.positionIds;
        this.project.subProjectIds.push(newSubProject.id); // Here is the id of subproject when it is pushed into interface of project
        this.store.dispatch(new UpsertSubProjectInternalAction(newSubProject));
        this.store.dispatch(new UpsertProjectInternalAction(this.project));
        this.newSubProjectName = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things here

1. Interfaces does not have parent child relations like what you wanted
2. This is bad practice . you should do this from this back end and not from front end . Consider the scenario , if you have shown that all sub projects are deleted and you have any error in database while deleting sub projects

In your case, delete the sub projects from database and reload updated sub projects on the front end.